# How do you cleanly stop a process started by a Windows service?

Tags: c#, .net, service, process

I have developed a program which runs as a Windows service.  This program starts a process to run another exe file.  It's developed in C# with .NET 6.0.

I know I can use

```
Process.Kill()
```

to terminate the process, but I'd like to try to end the process cleanly before killing it.  I've read through several other threads, but haven't found a solution that works.  The exe file that is run as a process does not have a GUI, so CloseMainWindow doesn't work.  Here is the code where I start the process.  When a CancellationToken arrives, the loop exits and the service tries to end the exe process.  exePath is the full path to the exe file.

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.FileName = exePath.Trim();
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

// Start the process with the info we specified.
// Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
{
    bool exited = false;

    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested && !exited)
    {
        exited = exeProcess.WaitForExit(1000);
    }
    if (!exited)
    {
        exeProcess.CloseMainWindow();  // THIS DOES NOT WORK!!!!
        exited = exeProcess.WaitForExit(5000);
    }
    if (!exited)
    {
        exeProcess.Kill();
        exited = exeProcess.WaitForExit(5000);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions or pointers to other threads would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: How does your Windows Service application receive and react to the command to stop?

Comment: When I stop the service, it receives the cancelation token and tries to end the process. I can tell it received the token because I added some logging. It does execute the Process.Kill, and the process ends, but not cleanly.